# Generating an array of random numbers with conditions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, random

I have a list of length 64, such as `first_list = [64, 27, 99, 133, 0, 41, ... ]`. Numbers in this are some random selection from `0` to `150` (minimum value is `0` and maximum value is `149`).

I want to generate several other list of random number with the same minimum and maximum condition (between `0` to `150`), and also in the new list (let's call it `new_list`), `new_list[0] != first_list[0]`, `new_list[1] != first_list[1]`, `new_list[2] != first_list[2]` , ...

Is there any fast way of implementing this?

Comment: Do you want to generate more than one new list that is element-wise all different from the first one (all the other ones?) ?

Comment: @Learningisamess yes :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest starting from a baseline 150x150 [latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) and extract a random selection of 64 columns.  This will give you 150 rows were you conditions are met with the baseline numbers.  Pick the number of rows you need at random from those 150.  Then establish a one-to-one random mapping of numbers 0..149 to a shuffled list of the same numbers and remap the numbers in your selected rows from that.

Given that the latin square never repeats numbers in the same column and that the one-to-one mapping will preserve this relationship. This will produce the randomized lists you're looking for.

Here is a function that generates a basic latin square of size n x n by shifting numbers by 1 on every row:

```
def lsquare(n):
    return [ [*range(i,n),*range(i)] for i in range(n) ]

print(*lsquare(5),sep="\n")

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
[3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Used with the randomization described above, you can obtain the desired lines:

```
from random import sample
def randLines(m,n,count):
    ls      = lsquare(n)
    cols    = sample(range(n),m)
    mapping = dict(enumerate(sample(range(n),n)))
    result  = [ [mapping[row[c]] for c in cols]
                for row in sample(ls,count) ]
    return result

print(*randLines(7,10,5),sep="\n")

[2, 9, 5, 3, 6, 8, 1]
[5, 7, 9, 2, 3, 0, 6]
[4, 6, 1, 0, 8, 2, 7]
[0, 1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 9]
[6, 2, 3, 1, 4, 9, 0]
```

Given that the baseline latin square's values could be computed using modulo arithmetics `(row + col) mod n`, we can avoid creating the whole latin square and the function could be  reduced to this:

```
def randLines(m,n,count):
    cols    = sample(range(n),m)
    mapping = dict(enumerate(sample(range(n),n)))
    return [[mapping[(r+c)%n] for c in cols] for r in sample(range(n),count)]
```

For 5 lines of 64 numbers out of 150:

```
print(*randLines(64,150,5),sep="\n")


[ 79,  97, 114,  29,  49,  46,  72,  40, 115,  24,  32, 142,  96,  51,  30, 121, 104, 144,  11,  62,  76,  44,  92,  21, 101,  95,  42, 113,   4,  74, 141,  22,  13,  23, 125, 118, 137, 149, 143,  59,  54,  55,  78,  83,  91, 106,  52,  65, 140,  14, 133,  36,  26, 134,  20,  33,  81, 103, 126,  39,   9,  80,  66, 100]
[  0,  79,  46,  42,  32, 122, 119,  22, 100, 142,  40,  64,  74, 102, 145, 104, 126,  75,  60,  87,  93,  97,  28,  96, 140, 116,  89,  41,  50,  77, 134, 137, 139,  58,   1, 144,  44,  71,  80, 114, 124, 113,   2, 133,  69,  48,  47, 112, 131, 147, 149,  14,  94,  73,  66,   9,   8,  88,  38, 106,  30, 120,  76,  56]
[ 33, 136,  80, 135,  69, 120,  20,  94,  47, 121,  26, 104, 115, 118,  67,  54, 124, 137,  27, 110,  19, 102, 105,  58,  50,  38,  49,  57,  71, 100, 139, 130,  76,  25,  17,  22,  51,  15,  65, 143,  68,  85,  97,  53, 127,  95,  10,  88,  43, 146,  16, 131,  42,  83,  12,  78,  46,  14,  82,  64,   2, 112, 123,  35]
[ 26,  69,  28, 121, 124,  17,  99,  39,  97, 117,  82,  65,  78, 116, 129, 103,  88,   7,  52,  35,  90,  91,  76,  75,  63, 107, 104,  31, 119,   2, 128, 106,   5, 137,  83,   6,  48,  20, 105,  92,  14,  77,  49, 113,  68, 120, 102,   4, 141,  15,  41,  16, 142,  18,  45,  42, 125, 149,  59,  80,  89, 101,  70,  79]
[ 51, 130,  14,  38, 106, 147,  55,  91, 109, 107,  48,  81,  61,  42,  75, 114,  46,  32,  86,  84,  34,  94,  16,  67,  73, 121,   6,  70,  83,  23,  72,  69,  41,  79,  71,  49,  26,  93, 131,  36,  80,  45,  22,  66,  64,  24,   9, 125, 111, 101,  76, 105, 116, 119,  85, 118,  88,  28, 122,  68, 144, 146,  57,  25]
```

Checking that all columns have different numbers (i.e. the set of each column's numbers has 5 distinct items):

```
lines = randLines(64,150,5)
print(all(len(set(col))==5 for col in zip(*lines))) # True
```

Based on the [Pigeon hole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you will not be able to get more than 150 lines without breaking the uniqueness conditions in columns.

Note that I assumed that "a selection from" meant the rows would also have distinct values, so 150 columns would also be a maximum.  If that was not your intention, then the solution would be a trivial one-liner: `*lines, = zip(*(sample(range(150),5) for _ in range(64)))`.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only two lists, try this:

```py
import random

lst = []
lst2 = []
hold = list(range(150))
random.shuffle(hold)

for i in range(64):
    lst.append(hold.pop())
    lst2.append(hold.pop())

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == lst2[i]:
        print("duplicate")
```

Lists should have different numbers at different positions

EDIT: if you want lots of lists, this should do:

```py
import random

num_lists = 150
list_holder = {}

for x in range(num_lists):
    list_holder[x] = []

hold = list(range(150))
random.shuffle(hold)

for i in range(64):
    for num, lst in list_holder.items():
        cnt = num+i
        if cnt >= 149:
            cnt = num+i-149
        lst.append(hold[cnt])

for x in list_holder.items():
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

You have `first_list`:

Now you want `new_list` *(a list of `64` elements from `0` to `149` elements that are not present in `first_list`)*

You can get unique values by:

```
unique_values = list(set(range(0,150)) - set(first_list))

import random
new_list = random.sample(unique_values, 64)
```

All the elements in `new_list` will be different from elements in `first_list`

---

Similarly you can carry on the process for `new_list[0]` but, there is a constraint as you need values only from `0` to `149` and you already have 2 lists of length 64 (`first_list, new_list`).

Now, to get another unique list of 64 length you may need to adjust your minimum and maximum values as `64 * 3 = 192` and your maximum range in `0 - 149`